# Taylor polynomial

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

I need your help to solve this question.
I tried something, but i can't finish my proof.

Let $f(x)$ be a differentiable function in $(0, \infty )$, so that $|f'(x)|$ is bounded there.
Prove that $\lim_{x \to \infty }\frac{f(x)}{x^{2}}=0$.

My solution:

$f(x)=f(x_{0})+f'(c)(x-x_{0})$ for $x_{0}>0 $.
$|f'(x)|$ is bounded by N:
$\left | \frac{f(x)}{x^2}  \right | =\left |\frac{f(x_{0})+f'(c)(x-x_{0})}{x^2}    \right |\leqslant 
\left |\frac{f(x_{0})}{x^2}  \right |+\left |\frac{f'(c)(x-x_{0})}{x^2}  \right |\leqslant \left |\frac{f(x_{0})}{x^2}  \right |+N\cdot \left |\frac{x-x_{0}}{x^2}  \right |$.

What is the next step?
Thanks!

Comment: Well, what's the limit of the right hand side? (You should indicate that $c$ depends on $x$.)

Comment: @ David Mitra.Oops, the limit of RHS is 0. thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think taylor is totally the wrong way, because of it's only an approximation. I would use that $|f'|$ bounded implies $f$ is lipschitz continuous with $$L=\sup |f'(x)|$$

I will do this by saying we have a function value on $0$. In fact there always exist a function with a greater domain which is continuous in $[0,\infty)$.
So we get $$\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} \frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x\cdot x}\leq \lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} \left| \frac{|f(x)-f(0)|}{x}\right| \cdot \frac{1}{x} \leq\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} L\cdot \frac{1}{x}=0$$